# Exception Details: System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied on Azure

Tags: azure, google-drive-api, google-sheets, azure-web-app-service

On my website (local), everything runs okay.

But for some reason, i get an error running it on Azure: [here is the link](http://traiteur-la-comida.azurewebsites.net/)

This is the stacktrace:

```
[HttpListenerException (0x5): Access is denied]
Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +82
Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task) +71
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.<AuthorizeAsync>d__6.MoveNext() +262

[AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.]
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) +3660541
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +10652281
Sapico.CMS.Drive.Connector.GetCredentials() +121
Sapico.CMS.Drive.<GetContent>d__f.MoveNext() +38
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
TraiteurLaComida.Site.Controllers.<Index>d__2.MoveNext() +527
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
lambda_method(Closure , Task ) +23
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task) +15
System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +68
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass34.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__33(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +16
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c() +50
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() +225
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() +225
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19() +26
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9515776
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

It seems to be the Google OAuth2 which i require in one of my dll's (implemented a connection to Google Drive using OAuth2, tested it from a console app and my local IIS website) ...

Any idea on how to fix this or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

My guess by reading the stack trace is that Sapico.CMS.Drive.Connector.GetCredentials() method is trying to open a port is listens for OAuth2 callback. This is not possible in Azure Web sites.

try to find if there is a way for the drive connector to provide a callback URL instead where the website is already listening. This will be more compliant with OAuth2 protocol(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)!